# Safest way to access a session scope bean in another bean

Tags: jsf, arguments, managed-bean

I am new to jsf and using JSF 2.0 to keep user information in a session scoped bean. I need to access this information across other beans for grunt work. Presently, this is how i am doing:-

```
private UserBean myuser1 = (UserBean)FacesUtils.getManagedBean("UserBean");
and then access properties as 
if (myuser1.getUserType == 1) ...
```

this works but some time throws Argument Error: parameter key is null exception. I have been using following method too:-

```
private UserBean myuser2 = new UserBean();
if (myuser2.getUserType == 1) ...
```

In second method, my understanding is that if UserBean is already created in session, it would be retried. There are lots of question about 'how to access one bean in another' so i am confused. Please tell me one clean method which should always work and not throw null pointer exception abruptly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know of is using `@ManagedProperty`, I don't know what you mean by safest though.
Let's say this is your sessionScoped bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScopped
public class UserBean {
  //bean attributes and methods
}
```

Then you can access it in any other bean (provided it has the same or a narrower scope) as an attribute like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped //in this cas you can use SessionScoped, FlowScoped, or RequestScoped too
public class AnotherBean {
  @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
  UserBean userB;
  //rest of the bean
  //be sure to add getters and setters for the injected bean
}
```

For more details check [this](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the heads up, I've modified my answer to include code and more explanation.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is the 'old' JSF2 way, Using CDI instead is advised

Answer (score 0):

Your UserBean should be a stateful one.

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class UserBean
{
  private String name;
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName( String name_ ) { name = name_; }
}
```

And just inject it into a stateless bean to modify its state:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyStatelessBean
{
  @EJB
  private UserBean userBean;

  public String getUserName() { userBean.getName(); };
  public void setUserName( String name_ ) { userBean.setName( name_); }
}
```

Or you can access it from (not wider scoped) managed beans as well in the same way:

```
@ManagedBean
@Dependent
public class MyJSFManagedBean
{
  @EJB
  private UserBean userBean;
}
```

You wrote in your comment you does not use EJBs at all. The picture modify like this:

The UserBean should be a SessionScoped CDI bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
pubilc class UserBean
{}
```

The othe CDI bean should be in a nearer scope:

```
@Named
@Request // or @ViewScoped or @Dependent
public class OwnerBean
{
  @Inject
  UserBean userBean;

}
```

The container automatically takes care to create the beans in the right scope and insert them into the owers (any kind of container managed objects : servlets, filters, action listeners, JSF/CDI beans). You need to insert a wider scoped resource into a thinner scoped one.

Comment: I have expanded my answer with a CDI bean relation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,
 parameter key is null exception: it's either you didn't initialize the object witch can be solver with either adding 
    object = new Object(); // in the constructor of the class.

The second problem may be that the object is " DETACHED " you need to call the object using the method merge (with the entity manager).

A detached object is a known value but the JPA system doesn't know if it is the latest version from the DB or even sometimes the id value is not set for some reason (Not managed with jpa in other words it can be your case).

If em is your entity manager and you have the following function:

public Object latestVersion(Object o){ em.merge; }

In your Bean with:

@EJB
   Service service;

if you do em.latestVersion(o); the problem of detached object is solved.

And for the real answer:

To access a object from another view you can simply do the following.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
..... Bean1 {
public static Object o;
.....
```

### }

```
@ManagedBean
..... Bean 2 {
private Object b=Bean1.o;
.....
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice of setting dependency of a scoped bean in another scoped bean is to use @Inject annotation like 
@Inject UserBean userBean; in the bean you want use the UserBean object.